# If $f' \in L^2$, then $f$ also belongs in $L^2$?

Tags: analysis, sobolev-spaces

First, I would like to apologize if this is a silly question.
I know that

$$H^1 = \{f \in L^2 : f' \in L^2\}$$

My question is: for to check that a certain function belongs in $H^1$ it's suffices to show that $f'$ belongs in $L^2$? That is, exists a function outside $L^2$ such that whose (weak) derivative is in $L^2$?

Comment: What about $f(x)=\log x$ on $(1,\infty)$?

Comment: Oh yes, thank you. Do you know some example in a bounded domain?

Answer (score 0):

In unbounded domain, this is false. In dimension $d$, if the function has $f'\in L^2$ and is converging to $0$ at infinity, then by Sobolev embedding it is in $L^p$ for some $p> 2$.

In particular, in bounded domains, it is true since them $L^p\subset L^2$.